# CAS Recordstore SocketTimeoutException

Tags: socketexception, atg, endeca

While indexing from ATG, consistently we are getting the below error:

> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException
>   invoking http://(endeca-server):8500/ExmProd_en_data/: Read timed out

---

Here are the logs:

**JBoss server (ATG):**

```
2015-05-17 19:07:12,278 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.DataDocumentSubmitter] (ProcessItemThread-482) Will attempt to contact record store "ExmProd_en_data" on host "<endeca-server>" on port 8,500
...
(/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler-reusablejobhandler-ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin - Baseline) Bulk load completed with "true" result in 6,097,145 milliseconds.
2015-05-17 20:48:37,330 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.SchemaDocumentSubmitter] (/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler-reusablejobhandler-ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin - Baseline) Ending session of record store ExmProd_en_schema with transactionId 48 (submitted 11,531 records).
2015-05-17 20:48:37,415 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.DimensionDocumentSubmitter] (/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler-reusablejobhandler-ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin - Baseline) Ending session of record store ExmProd_en_dimvals with transactionId 48 (submitted 178,870 records).
2015-05-17 20:48:38,112 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.DataDocumentSubmitter] (/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler-reusablejobhandler-ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin - Baseline) Ending session of record store ExmProd_en_data with transactionId 48 (submitted 1,127,618 records).
...
2015-05-17 21:18:38,164 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler-reusablejobhandler-ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin - Baseline) Interceptor for {http://recordstore.itl.endeca.com/}RecordStoreService#{http://recordstore.itl.endeca.com/}commitTransaction has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.commitTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at atg.endeca.index.RecordStoreDocumentSubmitterSessionImpl.endSession(RecordStoreDocumentSubmitterSessionImpl.java:593)
    at atg.endeca.index.AbstractRecordStoreAggregateSession.commitPending(AbstractRecordStoreAggregateSession.java:494)
    at atg.endeca.index.AbstractRecordStoreAggregateSession.endSession(AbstractRecordStoreAggregateSession.java:432)
    at atg.endeca.index.RecordSubmitterImpl.endSession(RecordSubmitterImpl.java:231)
    at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingPhase.doPhaseCleanup(IndexingPhase.java:376)
    at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingPhase.performPhaseTasks(IndexingPhase.java:324)
    at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingPhase.performPhaseTasksSerially(IndexingPhase.java:243)
    at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingJob.performJobSerially(IndexingJob.java:281)
    at com.example.commerce.endeca.index.admin.EXMSimpleIndexingAdmin.indexBaseline(EXMSimpleIndexingAdmin.java:428)
    at atg.endeca.index.admin.SimpleIndexingAdmin.indexBaseline(SimpleIndexingAdmin.java:637)
    at com.example.commerce.endeca.index.admin.EXMSimpleIndexingAdmin.indexBaseline(EXMSimpleIndexingAdmin.java:262)
    at atg.endeca.index.admin.SimpleIndexingAdmin.performScheduledTask(SimpleIndexingAdmin.java:867)
    at atg.service.scheduler.ScheduledJob.runJobs(ScheduledJob.java:479)
    at atg.service.scheduler.Scheduler$2handler.run(Scheduler.java:780)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://<endeca-server>:8500/ExmProd_en_data/: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1457)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1442)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.close(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:658)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:698)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:641)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1218)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1577)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1428)
    ... 27 more
```

**Endeca CAS server (cas-service.log):**

(No ERRORs were found in the log, only the below WARNing is getting repeated often)

```
2015-05-15 03:13:02,486 WARN [ExmProd_en_data] [ExmProd_en_data-cleaner-1] com.endeca.itl.recordstore.impl.Cleaner: Exception caught while performing cleanup
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cleans while transactions are active not implemented yet
    at com.endeca.itl.recordstore.impl.RecordStoreImpl.clean(RecordStoreImpl.java:566)
    at com.endeca.itl.recordstore.impl.Cleaner$1.run(Cleaner.java:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.endeca.itl.util.LoggingContextAwareThread.run(LoggingContextAwareThread.java:26)
```

---

ATG Version: **10.2** (ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin)
Endeca Version: **3.1.2** (pipeline based, i.e., Forge -> Dgidx).

Any help in fixing this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: In your `DataIngest.xml`, what is the value of your `httpSocketTimeout` in the `CAS` component? Try and increase this and see if it helps.

Comment: @radimpe It uses Forge and not CAS Crawler.  Correct me if I am wrong, the `CAS` component helps only in CAS Crawling.

Comment: It must be using `CAS`, or why did you provide the `cas-service.log`. Also, the `ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin` will be calling `CAS` in order to generate the files you need. The 'RecordStoreService` is also part of `CAS`. The `ATG - ENDECA` integration does not use forge at all. It is `CAS` and then `DGIDX`.

Comment: @radimpe I think you are referring to 11.x version of Oracle Commerce.  But before that, even `ATG - Endeca` integration used `Forge` not `CAS Crawling` (when you use _ProductCatalog based DeploymentTemplate_).  I can confirm that by looking at the `DataIngest.xml` where I have a line `Forge.run();`.  ATG pushes its data to CAS recordstores and then Forge picks it up (using RecordAdapter of pipeline) from the CAS recordstores (hence log captured in `cas-service.log`).

Comment: @radimpe - really appreciate your suggestions.  I stumbled a bit but able to find a solution, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digged through the source code and figured out that the class `com.endeca.itl.service.ServiceLocator` has a socket timeout setting for this.

---

## Solution:

Set the environment variable `com.endeca.itl.socketReceiveTimeout` to a much higher value than the current socket timeout time.

For example, `–Dcom.endeca.itl.socketReceiveTimeout=3600000` in your appropriate java VM of the server and rerun).

(Default is 30 minutes = 1800000 milli seconds).

(It’s so unfortunate that Oracle didn’t document such an important environment-specific configuration anywhere and what’s even more surprising is that such configuration are kept in private fields with read-only access; This should have been an explicit property in all the IndexingOutputConfig components).